# Load balancing multiple http sources for a stream

Tags: spring-xd

I am getting started to play with Spring-XD. In my current architecture, i am planning on to have log events aggregation stream deployed to Spring-XD.
http|elastic or http|kafka or http|hadoop.
I am planning to have multiple http modules deployed one per xd-container to be able to handle the load of several log events coming from different applications. Per online forums, it was suggested that  i use external load balancer to distribute the http load to several containers where http sources are deployed. This is doable, but not a good approach, if you plan on to have several streams with http sources (using different ports for each stream). You now have configuration information spread out to external LoadBalancer instead of xd-admin. Theoretically xd-admin has the information and it is best placed for distributing the load, if we can push the data to a xd-admin instead of directly to xd-containers.
Typical http post will look like
http://xd-admin-host-IPAddress:Port/StreamName
Then xd-admin with its knowledge can do the load balancing to several xd-containers where http sources are deployed.

Did anyone run into this scenario? Can this be a feature/enhancement request to spring-xd team?